# Count TextBox Filled (Only Some)

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I am trying to count 7 textboxes if they are filled I am going to multiply for each one the value of 10.50, but I am not able to do this verification ... I made the code below but it is not working with the

> error 91

```
Sub btnCal_Click()

    Dim cont As Integer
    Dim ctrl As Control

    cont = 1

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            If Not IsNull(ctrl.Value) And Left(ctrl.Name, 6) = "txtDp" & cont Then
                cont = cont + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    txtEx.Value = ctrl * 10.5

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you mean this instead... `txtEx.Value = cont * 10.5`?

Comment: hanks, the error left, but when I enter 2 values ​​in 2 textBox it is not adding the two ... I know it should be my oversight but what should I do to calculate it ... since the value after inserting two fields should being 21.00 but appearing 10.50

Comment: where are you adding two values?

Comment: txtDp1 and txtDp2.

Comment: so loop the controls and check against the names txtDp1 and txtDp2 and add...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you need to add the values contained in the textboxes and then multiply by 10.5.  If this is correct, then try the following code:

```
Private Sub btnCal_Click()
   Dim cont As Integer
   Dim ctrl As Control

   cont = 0

   For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
         If Val(ctrl.Text) <> 0 And Left(ctrl.Name, 5) = "txtDp" Then
            cont = cont + Val(ctrl.Text)
         End If
      End If
   Next ctrl

   txtEx.Text = cont * 10.5
End Sub
```

Comment: tks Brian, but when I test the value here (txtEx.Text = cont * 10.5) it is appearing zero ...

Comment: Did you copy and paste the entire Sub?  There were a number of errors I corrected.

Comment: yes this is all correct as you described, the error disappeared but now only mutaple of each textbox ... this way (when I insert a value in txtDP1 it inform in txtEx.Text the value of 10.50 when I inform another value in txtDp2 should add no txtEx.Text = txtDp1 + txtDp2 thus resulting in the value of 21.00

Comment: With the above code, if I put a 1 in txtDp1 and a 1 in txtDp2 and click the button, txtEx is 21.  Do you not get this same result?

Comment: I've pasted your complete code ... but on mine when I run 0 appears ... 
in the field txtEx.Text = cont * 10.5

Comment: My recommendation would be to set a break point in the Sub and step through the code.  Then you can see what is happening.

Comment: Ok I will try but I am some time with this code and everything I try is not working .. kkk

Comment: I wrote this code but it is still zeroing txtEx ... can anyone help me please ...